# Proof of the Central Limit Theorem using moment generating functions

Tags: limits, statistics, central-limit-theorem, moment-generating-functions

Below is a method of proving the Central Limit Theorem using moment generating functions.

Let $$X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with expected value and variance $$E(X_{i}) = \mu < \infty,  Var(X_{i})=\sigma ^{2}< \infty.$$

Now let

$$Z_{n}=\frac{\overline{X}-\mu }{\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{n}-n\mu }{\sigma \sqrt{n}}.$$

We want to show that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_{Z_{n}}(t)=e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$$

where $M_{X}(t)$ is the moment generating function over some finite interval.  In order to prove this, we can define a new random variable, $Y_{i}$, which is the normalized version of $X_{i}$.  Thus,

$$Y_{i}=\frac{X_{i}-\mu }{\sigma }.$$
Then, we can say that $Y_{i}$ is i.i.d. with expected value and variance

$$E(X_{i}) =0,  Var(X_{i})=1.$$

Using this information, we have $$Z_{n}=\frac{\overline{Y}-\mu }{\frac{\sigma }{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{Y_{1}+Y_{2}+...+Y_{n} }{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Finding the moment generating function gives

$$M_{Z_{n}}(t)=E[e^{t\frac{Y_{1}+Y_{2}+...+Y_{n} }{\sqrt{n}}}] =E[e^{t\frac{Y_{1}}{\sqrt{n}}}]\cdot E[e^{t\frac{Y_{2}}{\sqrt{n}}}]\cdot ...\cdot E[e^{t\frac{Y_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}]= M_{Y_{1}}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^{n}.$$

Lastly,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} M_{Z_{n}}(t)=\lim_{n \to \infty} M_{Y_{1}}(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})^{n} = e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}.$$

This concludes the proof.  However, how does one show analytically that this final limit does indeed equal

$$e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}?$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By Taylor's theorem,
$$M_{Y_1}(s) = E[\exp(sY_1)] = 1 + s E[Y_1] + \frac{s^2}{2} E[Y_1^2] + s^2 h(s) = 1 + \frac{s^2}{2} + s^2 h(s), \qquad \text{where $h(s) \to 0$ as $s \to 0$},$$
where the last step uses $E[Y_1]=0$ and $\text{Var}(Y_1) = 1$.

Thus
$$M_{Y_1}(t/\sqrt{n})^n = \left(1 + \frac{t^2/2}{n} + \frac{t^2}{n} h(t^2/n)\right)^n \to e^{t^2/2}.$$
[The expression in parentheses is asymptotically equivalent to $1+\frac{t^2/2}{n}$, so the last step follows by recalling $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \to e^x$.]

---

Response to comment:

For $x$ near $0$, we have $\log(1+x) = x(1+g(x))$ where $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log M_{Y_1}(t/\sqrt{n})
\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} n(1-M_{Y_1}(t/\sqrt{n}))[1+g(1-M_{Y_1}(t/\sqrt{n}))]
\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{n\left(\frac{t^2/2}{n} + \frac{t^2}{n}h(t^2/n)\right)
\left[1+g\left(\frac{t^2/2}{n} + \frac{t^2}{n}h(t^2/n)\right)\right]\right\}
\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{t^2/2}{n} + \frac{t^2}{n}h(t^2/n)\right)
\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[1+g\left(\frac{t^2/2}{n} + \frac{t^2}{n}h(t^2/n)\right)\right]
\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{t^2/2}{n} + \frac{t^2}{n}h(t^2/n)\right)
\\
&= \frac{t^2}{2} + t^2 \lim_{n \to \infty}h(t^2/n)
\\
&= \frac{t^2}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: For your final step, you argue that it is justified to first take a limit within the parentheses, and then take a limit of the whole. Why would this be right?

Comment: @Interestedstudent I have updated my answer with a more rigorous explanation

Comment: @angryavian: Don't we have to show $\frac{t^2}{n} h(t^2/n)$ is $o(1/n)$?

Comment: @Ashok No, all we need is that this term tends to zero as $n \to \infty$. This is true because $h(s) \to 0$ as $s \to 0$, based on the application of Taylor's theorem in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @angryavian Sorry, how can that be? Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{3}{n})^n = e$?

Comment: @Ashok Sorry, my last comment was inaccurate. But doesn't $\lim_{s \to 0} h(s) = 0$ imply $\frac{t^2}{n} h(t^2/n) = o(1/n)$? The work below the horizontal line does use the fact that the term is $o(1/n)$.

Comment: @angryavian: Yes, you are right!

Comment: @angryavian: Do you have any good reference to the proof of the result "If $M_{X_n}(t)\to M_X(t)$, then $X_n\to^d X$?

Comment: @Ashok The answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/181038/21801) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/856527/43949) have some discussion and references.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks a lot!

Comment: @angryavian Hello. I have a question about $h(s) \rightarrow 0$ as $s \rightarrow 0$. How can we be sure that some higher moments $E[Y^k]$ inside the term $h(s)$ are finite? What if some moment $E[Y^k]$ are infinite? Won't that cause $h(s)$ to explode? Please explain; thank you.

Comment: @angryavian Adding to my previous question: For example, I think a Pareto distribution can have finite mean and variance but infinite higher moments. In this case, how does the proof still work?

Comment: The proof that OP is using assumes the MGF exists, and cannot be applied in cases where it does not exist. However, there is a [similar proof using characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Proof_of_classical_CLT) instead. For characteristic functions, [the existence of the first two moments implies the characteristic function is twice continuously differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Properties), so the second-order Taylor approximation holds. @TrueWarrior09