# Use MGF to show $\hat\beta$ is a consistent estimator of $\beta$

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

Suppose that $X_1,....,X_n$ is a random sample from a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha= 2, \beta$.

\begin{equation}
f(x)= \frac{x e^{(-x/ \beta)}}{\beta^2},  x>0
\end{equation}
(a) Find the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat\beta$ of $\beta$  and show it is unbiased.

(b) Use the moment generating function (MGF) to show that $\hat\beta$ is a consistent estimator of $\beta$.

I Know the answer for part (a) $\hat\beta= \frac{1}{2n} \sum {X_i}$ and then show $E[\hat\beta]= \beta$.

I need help in part (b) I know how to show that an estimator is consistent by using convergence in probability definition or 
 Chebyshev's Inequality. but I have no idea how to use MGF to show  an estimator is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the mgf of $\hat{\beta},$ $\mathbb{E}(\exp(\hat{\beta}t))$ converges to $\exp(\beta t).$ Note that $\exp(\beta t)$ is the MGF of the degenerate random variable $\beta.$

The convergence of MGF implies convergence in distribution. [Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856055/how-to-prove-that-convergence-in-mgf-implies-convergence-in-distribution)

Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to the same constant. [Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716298/proof-for-convergence-in-distribution-implying-convergence-in-probability-for-co)